# How to match only the exact word using indexOf or includes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to search only the specific word in my string using javascript. But using match, indexOf  or includes are not working properly. Suppose

```
    let str = "Widget test";

   if (~str.indexOf("Widge")) {
    console.log( 'Found it!' );
    }
```

it will print found it as it is not matching the whole word only the substring. How can I return it to found if only the match is Widget

But what I want is :

if input string = Widget, output =  true

if input string = Widge , output =  false

Comment: What are some possible inputs and outputs?

Comment: @JamesCoyle edited, check now

Comment: just use `str == "Widget"` and if you want to match any word use `str.split(/\s+/)` use indexOf on array.

Comment: Your check is the wrong way round,..  try -> `~"Widge".indexOf("Widget")`

Comment: Any reason to favour the bitwise operator over `String.contains`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To match the exact word you can use a regular expression.

`/\bWidget\b/` will match the entire word.

In your example:

```
let str = "Widget";

if (str.search(/\bWidget\b/) >= 0) {
 console.log( 'Found it!' );
}
```

Comment: RegEx are ideal for these type of things, but -> `you will have to`, that's not true.

Comment: You are right, it is only one approach to this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this also.

```
let str = "Widget test";
if(str.split(" ").indexOf('Widge') > -1) {
    console.log( 'Found it!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to answer this question, the correct answer was provided. And it also was a bit unclear what OP actually wants...

...so in the mean time I wrote this awful ~hack~ solution:

```js
const matchType = (source = '', target = '') => {
  const match = source.match(target) || [];
  return (!isNaN(match.index) && !!~match.index)
    ? match.input === target ? 'complete' : 'partial'
    : 'none';
};

console.log(matchType('foo', 'bar'));
console.log(matchType('foo', 'fo'));
console.log(matchType('foo', 'foo'));
```

Now you can have three different type of matches, isn't it cool? :D

Answer (score 0):

if string not found than indexOf will return -1 so you can check index not equal to -1 than string found

```js
function match(){
var test = "Widget test";
if (test.indexOf("widget")!= -1) {
  alert( 'Found it!' );
}else{
alert( 'Sorry,not Found it!' );
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="match()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```
let str = "Widget test";

if (str.indexOf("wi")!= -1) {
  console.log( 'Found it!' ); 
}
```